# Modules and custom routes

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-framework-modules

I'm building a website using Zend Framework and having trouble implementing modules and custom routes.
There are basically two rules:

- Select a module based on the domain (multiple domains can select a single module)
- Regardless of domain, select one specific module based on path

Examples:

- domain1.com selects module domain1
- domain1.net selects module domain1
- domain2.com selects module domain2
- both domain1.com/admin and domain2.com/admin select module admin

This is the first project where I use ZF, so my experience with the framework is basically non-existent. I have done some dirty hacking in my bootstrapper where I check the domain and than execute `Zend_Layout::startMVC()` to get the correct layout, but that is messed up when I'm implementing custom routes.

So I was wondering what is the best way to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Zend_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571213/zend-framwork-route-module-on-subdomain).